Migrate a large project using Require.js
I work on a fairly large Javascript project (~863 files), where all the code is distributed in a modular way, being practically one file per class (object-oriented). Some things are loaded on the fly, when they are needed. But most are compiled into a single final file (relatively heavy).
For this great task, at the time I decided to use Require.JS, a library that has been abandoned today. For each file I have declared an alias (auto-generated with a script that I have created), so almost all the headers are of the type:
define([
   "SistemaJS2",
   , ... <other dependencies>
   , "VistaJS2"
],
function(
   SistemaJS2
   , ... <other dependencies>
   , VistaJS2
) {
});

As migrating this is a gigantic and conflictive task, I ask you for any similar experience, recommendation, etc. What would be the most comfortable, flexible, powerful way to use modules in 2024?
Thanks
I have tried a few guides in the past to move to Webpack, but it seems it is no longer as cool.
